# Git commands in cron job

Tags: linux, cron

I am new to cron jobs. I want to run git commands through cron job.
I just tried a simple one with 'git status'.

I created a script

#!/bin/bash

echo `git status`

It is working when I run the script directly in the git view but not working in crontab.

I created the crontab as
* * * * * /path/to/script >> path/to/outputfile.

Please help me.

EDITED:
Please provide any sample program for running simple git commands in cronjob.

Comment: So what happens ? Note that cron sends you mail for your cron jobs. If they fail, you might find error messages there - access it with the 'mail' command, or look in the /var/spool/mail/yourusername file.

Comment: I checked the result through 'mail' commad. I am getting command not found at   /path/to/script.sh. I am giving complete git view path, my script exist in git view only

Comment: Are you sure your script has the execute bit set?

Comment: @user3610740 What do you mean by git view ?

Comment: @nos git view means my local repository path. I am new to linux environment. I hope you can understand what I am trying to say.                                                                                                                              @ rodrigo  I am getting output with ./script.sh.

Comment: error - git : command not found

Comment: Then perhaps the git command resides in a directory that is not in the PATH when the script is being run. You can figure out where the `git` command is by running `which git` , and then using the full path to `git` within the script, or add a directory to the PATH in your script.

Comment: Please suggest me a simple example to run any git command in crontab.

Comment: @user3610740 your example works fine. Its your environment that is odd/non-standard/strange, that we need to sort out - and that's why I ask you where you git command resides. i.e. which directory is the git executable file located.

Comment: @nos I will try to figure out the path.  Thank you so much for your guidance.                                                                                                      I tried with `which git`/git status but it is giving following error                   Not a git repository

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't need an

```
echo `git status`
```

to output text, if you call the script with the `>>`. That way, you just echo the output you'd get anyway.

Concerning your problem, as was already discussed, you can give the direct path to git (such as `/usr/local/bin/git`). Furthermore, the script probably won't be called in the directory where your git repo lies; you have to `cd` there first, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd <wherever your repo lies>
/usr/local/bin/git status
```

and then add that script in your crontab as you already did. Hope that helps.